# Why is my OR clause not working in SQLite Studio?

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

New to SQL, not sure if I'm missing something here, but wondering why my OR clause is not working here. It is only returning Doja Cat's info, not Olivia Rodrigo's

```
SELECT artist_name, track_name,
AVG(tempo),
AVG(danceability),
AVG(popularity),
AVG(loudness),
AVG(energy)
    FROM BIT_DB.Spotifydata
        WHERE artist_name = 'Doja Cat' OR 'Olivia Rodrigo'
GROUP BY artist_name, track_name
```

Comment: `WHERE artist_name = 'Doja Cat' OR artist_name = 'Olivia Rodrigo'`

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE artist_name = 'Doja Cat' OR artist_name = 'Olivia Rodrigo'
```

or

```
WHERE artist_name IN('Doja Cat', 'Olivia Rodrigo')
```